# Shutdown errors on ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS

Tags: lockup

The following picture shows the errors:

[image]

Comment: These errors are takes on every times while system shutdown.I don't know what's the reasons are.

Comment: Does the system shut itself down eventually, or does it just hang at this screen?

Comment: @NickWeinberg Thanks for reply.This case occurs when the system shutdown or restart after i clicked shutdown or reboot button.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your filesystem, because of the first four error messages. Boot to the emergency boot GRUB menu choice and drop down to `root` level and type `fsck -f /`. Run that command again, if need be, until it runs without errors.

Then, do you have Intel processors? If so, install `intel-microcode` and reboot the machine. In terminal, type `dmesg|grep microcode` to see that it's checking/updating the processor microcode.

Let me know if that helps with your shutdown problem. Cheers, Al

Comment: Ok,i'll try and synchronize the score here.thousands of thanks.

Comment: Did it help? Please tell use the results! Please vote/accept my answer if it helped. Cheers, Al

Comment: Good job,man.You saved my time and life, This is helpful in my situation.@heynnema